# DomNode get value of item

Tags: php, xml

Hello I'm new with domnode and i'm trying to check the values from an xml tree which loads ok.
Here is my code but I dont understand why is not working.

```
private function createCSV($xml, $f)
{

    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('*') as $item) 
    {

        $hasChild = $item->hasChildNodes() ? true : false;

        if(!$hasChild)
        {   
            //echo 'Doesn\'t have children';
            echo 'Value: ' . $item->nodeValue;
        }
        else
        {
            //echo 'Has children';
            $this->createCSV($item, $f);
        }
    }

}
```

`$item->nodeValue` doesnt print anything to the browser.
I read the documentation but I can't see any mistake.

PS. `$item->tagname` doesnt work either.

**UPDATE**

whe using this: `echo $item->ownerDocument->saveHTML($item);`

I get the tags listed but i dont get the data inside(between the tags) like innerHTML in javascript.

**UPDATE**

sample xml data : http://pastebin.com/dkuUUC0Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text nodes are also considered child nodes, but you're only iterating element nodes (get *Elements* ByTagName). Because of this you're almost never getting into the 2nd condition.

Try this:

```
if(!$xml->hasChildNodes()){
  printf('Value: %s', $xml->nodeValue);
  return;
}    

foreach($xml->childNodes as $item)
  $this->createCSV($item, $f);
```

XPath version:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$text = $xpath->query('//text()[normalize-space()]');
foreach($text as $node)
  printf('Value: %s', $node->nodeValue);
```

Comment: still printf only prints out 'Value:'

Comment: Can you post some sample XML data?

Comment: Seems to work for me - http://3v4l.org/KuQat. I used trim() to avoid printing empty text nodes (whitespace). But I think that Xpath and normalize-space() would be a nicer way to handle those situations

Comment: Thank you for your time it seems to work yes I still cant understand what the error was.. :)

Comment: In this similar case how can i print out the tag name? in order to create an associative array?

Comment: `hasChildNodes()` returns true on something like `<foo> bar </foo>`. Because the text `bar` is a child text node. You were not taking that into account. Also, you were using getElementsByTagName, which gets you only element-type nodes (text nodes are ignored). The `parentNode->tagName` property should get you the tag name of the element that contains the text